# InputFormatter for Single Request

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a way to include an `InputFormatter` which only runs for a single endpoint?
We have 1 solitary endpoint which has a need for a custom `InputFormatter`.
So we don't really want to add an input formatter globally, for the benefit of a single endpoint. I don't really want to write a hacky middleware which would run for every request either. Some kind of `ActionFilter` would have been perfect.

I've seen existing SO answers on this very topic, but they all have answers which require an outdated API e.g. the `InputFormatters` collection is no longer available on the context in Action Filters.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which helps you to control the input formatter for an action method.

```
public class CSPContentTypeFormatterAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var options = context
            .HttpContext
            .RequestServices
            .GetService(serviceType: typeof(IOptions<MvcOptions>)) as IOptions<MvcOptions>;
        var mvcOptions = options.Value;
        mvcOptions.InputFormatters.OfType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>().First()
            .SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
                new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/csp-report")
            );
        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, IOptions<T> is a singleton so the change will affect subsequent requests as well.

Comment: @MickaëlDerriey Thanks. If we remove it in the ActionExecuted it should fix the problem, right? Yes, I know it is not a very optimal solution.

Comment: Yeah. I considered that but disregarded it. It's so sub-optimal that I did not consider it a viable possibility. I went with a custom model binder, which I can specify to be used in the parameter list for the Action method. So, it won't be globally added.